# Getting rid of the session timeout in Excel Web Access?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, excel-services, session, refresh

I understand there is a 30 second short session timeout (if no interaction is detected) to a 5 minute extended sessiopn timeout. 
The userss would like their reports up all day, just refreshing every 10- 15 mins without timin out.

What is the best way to get this working??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wish to have your reports open all day along without a timeout , I am assuming you are using Excel Services for SharePoint 2010

In the central admin go to the - trusted datasource library > Session Management > Session Timeout and set this value to "-1".  This should prevent your time out messages for ever.

But this is certainly not a good practice to add.

The better way is to have a session timeout set to 6 hours followed by the excel application pool in IIS to recycle once in every 24 hours (during non peak hours). Predicting performance of a service application in SharePoint is a highly non deterministic thing as there are galaxies of configurations,factors on different levels (os,iis,sql) that come into consideration.However as a general rule of thumb you can go with the above suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the info! We have just a handful of reports so it shoudnt really affect performance in anyway.